# OpenCV Distance transform is not working as it supposed to

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to use OpenCV to divide an image with resolution 2048x2048 into smaller images for some *pixels with resolution 90x90 around that pixel. Later on those smaller images I want to use foveation. I followed this example on foveation an image, but instead python I am using C++.

[Image foveation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910285/image-foveation-in-python)

```
       Mat mask = Mat::ones(Size(90,90), CV_8UC1) * 255;
       circle(mask, CvPoint(45,45), 30, 0, -1);

       Mat out; // = Mat::ones(Size(90,90), CV_32FC1) * 0;
       distanceTransform(mask, out, CV_DIST_L2, CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE);


       int scale_factor = 10;
       Mat filtered = outputImage.clone();
       Mat img_float;
       filtered.convertTo(img_float,CV_32F,1,0);

       for(int k = 0; k < 90; k++){  // y
            for(int l = 0; l < 90; l++){  // x
                if(out.at<float>(k,l) == 0.0) continue;

                float mask_val = ceil(out.at<float>(k,l)/scale_factor);
                if(mask_val <= 3) mask_val = 3;

                int beginx = l - int(mask_val/2);
                if (beginx < 0)
                    beginx = 0;

                int beginy = k - int(mask_val/2);
                if (beginy < 0)
                    beginy = 0;

                int endx = l+int(mask_val/2);
                if (endx >= 90)
                    endx = 90-1;

                int endy = k+int(mask_val/2);
                if (endy >= 90)
                    endy = 90-1;

                int num = 0;
                float total = 0; 
                for (int a = beginx; a < endx; a++){
                    for(int b = beginy; b < endy; b++){
                        num ++;
                        total += img_float.at<float>(a,b);
                    }
                }

                filtered.at<float>(k,l) = (total/num);
            }
       }

       namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
       imshow( "Display window", filtered );
       waitKey(0); 
       imwrite( ss.str(), filtered, compression_params );
```

In another question here I read that instead of using 3 or 5 as a parameter in distanceTransform I should use CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE.

The problem is that my Mat out is sometimes black, and sometimes white with a circle but it can not be saved or used in the code.

Here are the results: 
[image]

But when I use the python script I don't have a problem: 
[image]

Specifications:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- CPU: i7-2600 3.50GHz
- RAM: 8GB

OpenCV ver. 3.0.0

*I said for some pixel, ~ 3 millions pixels.

**EDIT** 
Here is the rest of the code. This part in the question goes right before saving the cropped image. 
http://pastebin.com/49rLhDcF 
Mat outputImage = temp( Rect(lx, ty, abs(rx - lx), abs(by-ty)));

ps: Because there a lot of pixel, after generating large amount of images I get **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**. I know this has to do with the memory and I am trying it to fix it, but I like to hear also your opinion.

Comment: ` img_float.at<float>(a,b);`   <-- a,b in wrong order.

Comment: probably you have `outputImage` to be a three channel matrix. You somehow messed up 1 channel images and 3 channel images. More code could help..

Comment: @Miki here is the source code
http://pastebin.com/49rLhDcF
I just change it today and run it. All the changes I will have to applied on Monday. 
So far, the code from the question goes before saving the modified (cropped) image.

Comment: I can't understand how this code is linked with yours

Comment: @Miki Mat filtered = outputImage.clone();

Ok, here is the scenario .... deep learning project. You have a high resolution picture, you divide it into smaller ones 90x90 for each pixel. Then before saving it imwrite  - you use foveation.
That part was taken away. Just imagine that is in line 263.

Also it may confuse you, but the pixels are labelled .. and it is a messy code. I will try to make it smaller tonight, functions and etc..

Comment: @Stefan ops, I was looking at the wrong link. I'll give it a try later (if I have time.. :D )

Comment: @Miki thank you :)) it is just a school project, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I read the documentation and everything looks good. But there are always surprise like this :(

Comment: If you have a minimal complete verifiable example that would be a lot easier..

Comment: email me: scvetkovski7@gmail.com and I would send you the whole code with examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83027/discussion-between-stefan-and-miki).

Comment: @Stefan thanks, but NO. SO is **not** a debugging team. Try to reproduce your error in a minimal complete verifiable code, and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,
I just add this lines.

I used Gaussian Blur to smooth the whole picture, and then I copied the value of the original pixel to preform the effect I want.

```
 for(int j = 0; j <  pixels_gray.size(); j++) {
               int x = pixels_gray[j].x;
               int y = pixels_gray[j].y;
               int lx = pixels_gray[j].lx;
               int rx = pixels_gray[j].rx;
               int ty = pixels_gray[j].ty;
               int by = pixels_gray[j].by;

               Mat outputImage = image_original( Rect(lx, ty, abs(rx - lx), abs(by-ty)));

               Mat mask = Mat::ones(Size(90,90), CV_8UC1) * 255;
               CvPoint      c = cvPoint(45, 45);
               circle(mask, c, 30, 0, -1);

               Mat smooth;

               for (int i=1; i<11; i=i+2){
                    GaussianBlur( outputImage, smooth, Size( i, i ), 0, 0 );
                }


                for(int my = 0; my < 90; my++){
                    for(int mx = 0; mx <90; mx++){
                        Scalar colour = mask.at<uchar>(Point(mx, my));
                        if(colour.val[0]==255) continue;
                        smooth.at<Vec3b>(my,mx)[0] = outputImage.at<Vec3b>(my,mx)[0];
                        smooth.at<Vec3b>(my,mx)[1] = outputImage.at<Vec3b>(my,mx)[1];
                        smooth.at<Vec3b>(my,mx)[2] = outputImage.at<Vec3b>(my,mx)[2];
                    }
                }


               stringstream ss;
               ss << dir << "gray_" << y << "_" << x << ".png";
               imwrite( ss.str(), smooth, compression_params );


           }
```